# Search and return tag name based off attribute within the tag xml bash

Tags: xml, bash, terminal, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I have a tag which contains a "name" attribute. The tag (xsd:tag1) itself is **not** unique within the XML file but the name attribute (name1) is unique. How can I search and return the tag name (i.e. to return xsd:tag1) using `xmlstarlet` or otherwise? An example of the XML is shown below.

```
<doc xmlns:xsd="http://example.com">
   <xsd:parentTag>
      <xsd:tag1 name="name1" />
   </xsd:parentTag>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example input you provide has two problems:

- `<xsd:tag1 name="name1">` has to be closed
- The namespace prefix `xsd:` has to be defined

If the file `input.xml` is as follows:

```
<doc xmlns:xsd="http://example.com">
 <xsd:parentTag>
  <xsd:tag1 name="name1" />
 </xsd:parentTag>
</doc>
```

the following command

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//*[@name='name1']" -v 'name()' input.xml
```

yields

```
xsd:tag1
```

The trick is to have a correct `xmlns` declaration in the input, in order to avoid `xmlstarlet` complain about undefined namespaces.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Good catch on the xmlns declaration. To be honest, I modified it so that it doesn't include the exact declaration in which I'm working with so it was a few copy and paste errors! I will also edit the post so that it reflects your comment.